# Does gdb 'thread apply all bt' loop through threads in sequence? Can it be faster?

Tags: gdb

The gdb 'thread apply all bt' command always take a very long time(usually hours) for a large core dump file -- for a quite complex system with thousands or tens of thousands of threads.

It looks the command loops through threads sequentially according to pid. I'm wondering if its possible to make the iteration in parallel, or any other ways to make it faster.

Comment: How large is the core file? I'd guess that gdb is i/o bound in this case, but you could try running multiple gdb's in parallel, each doing bt's on a subset of all the threads.

Comment: The core file is pretty large, easily over 10GB -- it's a full dump with all the memory content. Anyhow, the process/thread info should be structured, gdb doesn't have to scan the whole file to get the backtrace, so it doesn't have to take hours, right?

Comment: It has to read through each frame of each stack, then read debug info from the executables, if that hasn't already been read. How big are the stacks? How large are the executables, and how much RAM do you have? There could be a lot of thrashing if you have multi-gigabyte debug info and not a lot of RAM (I've seen some C++ apps that have more than 6GB of debug info.)

Comment: The executable and debug info is not big, around hundreds of MBs. The debug machine has 16GB RAM. (does gdb load the whole core file into memory?) The stacks are typically of depth 20-40.

Comment: gdb doesn't load the entire core file into memory. If you have enough RAM that everything gdb needs to access can fit in cache, it's puzzling why things would be slow. Does gdb seem to gradually slow down as it iterates through all the threads? Maybe there's a memory leak - run `top` in a separate window and see if gdb grows large or starts to use a high percentage of cpu time

Comment: `thousands or tens of thousands of threads` unless you have some monster system, it seems like your program is poorly written. You start to experience diminishing returns if the number of threads you have is too much larger than the number of cores you have. If you say you have `tens of thousands of threads`, then I expect you to have *minimum* one thousand cores for 10k threads. MINIMUM. Even with that I expect your performance will be suboptimal, though testing would be required even if that were true.